# Immutable.js performance slow with toJS()

Tags: immutable.js

We are using **Immutable.js** in our flux archtiecture.

Our state object is a fairly complex tree with thousands of nodes in it. We have no choice but to send this as a JSON object back to the server.

We are using **data.toJS()** to convert to JSON, however it takes about 2 seconds to finish this call. It is unfortunately too slow for us.

Is there a better solution to our problem?

Comment: Calculate and send only nodes that were updated? stringifying complex data structures into JSON is expensive regardless of what library you use, that's just something you have to accept.

Comment: yeah, hoping there is an easier way though

Comment: Easy or more efficient... in this case, you will need to try and find a balance.

Comment: We have the same problem and we fixed it by using https://github.com/intelie/immutable-js-diff and https://github.com/intelie/immutable-js-patch

You can use https://github.com/glenjamin/transit-immutable-js to send data between the clients and the server.